# Slightly inaccurate results when converting floating point binary to decimal

Tags: c, binary, decimal

What it should do:
Input example - 101.101
output - 5.625

This is the way I wrote a floating point binary - decimal converter but there is
a small error - the problem is the output is not accurate to the correct decimal point.

What my code does:
Input - 101.101
Output - 5.624985

What my code does when I changed count from -16 to -32:

Input - 101.101 Output - 5.625000 This is correct.

Input - 101.111 Output - 5.875061 This is still off it should be 5.875

```
#include <stdio.h>

double decimal(double decpart);
long int integer(long int intpart);

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    double x;
    scanf("%lf", &x);
    long int intpart = (long int)x;
    double decpart = x-intpart;

    double finint = integer(intpart);
    double findec = decimal(decpart);

    double finnum = findec + finint;
    printf("%lf\n",finnum);

    return 0;
}

long int integer(long int intpart)
{
    double sum = 0;
    long int a, b, p= 0;

while(intpart>0)
{
    a = intpart % 10;
    b = a*(pow(2, p));
    sum = sum + b;
    p++;
    intpart = intpart / 10;
}
    return sum;
}

double decimal(double decpart)
{
    double sum = 0;
    int count = 0;
    while (decpart > 0 && count > -32)
    {
        count--;
        decpart = decpart*10;
        if (decpart >= 1)
        {
            decpart = decpart - 1;
            sum = sum + pow(2, count);
        }
    }

    return sum;
}
```

Comment: I don't see the purpose of your 'intoart()' function. A cast would do the same thing. Your 'decimal()' function is misnamed.

Comment: None of this program involves any decimal. You are reading a binary text string into a `double`, but `double` is not decimal. It would be easier to read the binary string into a `long` while ignoring the radix point, then use the position of the radix point to calculate the second argument to `ldexp`.

Answer (score 2):

The inaccuracy is a rounding error built up from the `pow` function which almost always has a small error, even for integer arguments. This is because `pow(x, y)` is often implemented based on the mathematical identity as `exp(log(x) * y)`, where `log` and `exp` use the natural base `2.718281828...`. Thus, even when e.g. the base is 2, `log(2)` is an approximation, so `exp(log(2))` will be even more of an approximation.

In your situation, rather than using `count` and `pow`, you can have a `double value` field that starts off at `0.5`, and is multiplied by `0.5` after each iteration:

```
double decimal(double decpart)
{
    double sum = 0;
    double value = 0.5;
    while (decpart > 0 && value > 1.0e-5) // approx. 2 ^ -16
    {
        decpart = decpart*10;
        printf("%lf\n",decpart);
        if (decpart > 1)
        {
            decpart = decpart - 1;
            sum = sum + value;
        }
        value *= 0.5;
    }

    return sum;
}
```

In general, this will be more accurate than the `pow` alternative. On IEEE-754 compliant systems (most modern systems are), `value` *should* always be the exact value you want.

---

Further, as I/others have mentioned, using `scanf` to read in the input as a `double` instead of a string *also* leads to inaccuracies, as numbers like 0.1 often cannot be stored exactly. Instead, you should input to a `char` array, then parse the string.

Comment: I used your code in place of mine and I still get the same output 5.624985 for 101.101

Comment: @blembo that's because when you use `scanf` to get the input of `101.101`, you're actually getting `101.10099792480469`, which is not what you want. Instead, you need to grab the *string* `"101.101"`, and look at each digit individually.

Comment: My `pow(x,y)` experience differs.  More often I've seen `pow(x) = expN(logN(x) * y)` where `N` is the base of the machine - typically `2` or `10`.   Further the `logN(x) * y` product typically uses extended precision.  Strongly doubt OP's `pow(2, y)` provided a non-exact answer.

Comment: @DrewMcGowen: I suspect that's the entire problem (unless there are other errors in the OP's code; I haven't checked). Consider posting that as an answer.

Comment: @Keith Thompson and Drew.  I now see a greater impact of "101.101 vs. 101.10099792480469" than before and amended my comment here.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is `-16` which is only 1 part in 65,536  or (0.0000153...).  The answer you get and desire are within that range.  Instead, need a more negative value like -32 or -53. (or about `ln2(DBL_EPSILON)`)   -

[Edit2] Values like -17, -18 , etc have additional problems. see below.

Also `if (decpart > 1)` --> `if (decpart >= 1)`.

---

[Edit]

Per the C spec with `DBL_MIN_10_EXP` at *most*  `-37` and typical binary floating point, a reasonable `pow(2, count)` will provide *exact* answers for `count` int the range `-80` to `+80`.

Your method of reading a decimal number and treating like a binary FP number likely breaks down once N significant digits are entered ("101.101" being 6).  Expect `N` to be something like `1/DBL_EPSILON` or at least 8 or 9 digits.  To get beyond that limit, suggest @Drew McGowen advice and read and process your input as a string.

[Edit2]

Given a typical `double` the limit of `N` significant digits is about 16 or 17.  Not only does this limit the input, it *also* limits the number of iterations in the `while (decpart > 0 && count > -16)`.  Going much deeper than that, the string to FP conversion of "101.111" (which is more like `101.111000000000004...`) yield unexpected results, acts like `101.111000000000001111111...`

> (Mathematically correct 101 + 1*1/2 + 1*1/4 + 1*1/8 + 1*pow(2,-15) + 1*pow(2,-16))) ... = 5.875061

So.....  Iterating `decimal()` more than `log10(1/DBL_EPSILON)` or about 15,16 times, begins to generate crap.  Yet code iterating 16 times only provides a decimal precision of 1 part in 65,536 (0.000015...).  Therefore to get answers better than that a new approach (like a string @Drew McGowen, inspired by @BLUEPIXY) is needed.

```
double BinaryFloatinPoint(const char *s) {
  double sum = 0.0;
  double power = 1.0;
  char dp = '.';  // binary radix point
  while (*s) {
    if (*s == '0' || *s == '1') {
      sum *= 2.0;
      sum += *s - '0';
      power *= 0.5;
    } else if (*s == dp) {
      dp = '0';
      power = 1.0;
    } else {
      return 0.0; // Unexpected char, maybe return NAN instead
    }
    s++;
  }
  if (dp == '0') {  // If dp found ...
    sum *= power;
  }
  return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Can not be expressed exactly because the number, such as `0.1` (10)  is an infinite decimal in binary.
So I suggest that you convert the input as a string.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

double bstrtod(const char *bstr){
    double x = 0, one = 1.0;
    char *p = strchr(bstr, '.');
    if(p){
        char *fp = p;
        while(*++fp){
            one /= 2.0;
            if(*fp=='1')
                x += one;
        }
    } else {
        p = strchr(bstr, '\0');
    }
    one = 1.0;
    do{
        if(*--p == '1')
            x += one;
        one *= 2.0;
    }while(p!=bstr);

    return x;
}

int main(void){
    double x = bstrtod("101.101");
    printf("%f\n", x);//5.625000
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Drew McGowen Agreed.  Although it does not address the weaknesses of OP's code which is limited in its range and precision, this code does the job. +1

Answer (score 0):

This inaccuracy comes from errors during rounding off. Even if you input 8, it actually stores 7.99999... That's why the problem occurs.

Comment: While it *is* rounding errors, integers are almost *always* stored exactly as input (except at very large integers; around 16777216, 32-bit floats can't store every integer).

Answer (score 0):

**Accurate Floating Point Binary to Decimal Converter**

This code uses strings to convert a binary input to a decimal output

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

double blembo(const char *blem);

int main(void)
{
    char input[50];
    gets(input);

    int t = 0, flag = 0;
    while (input[t] != '\0')  // This whole block of code invalidates "hello" or "921" or "1.1.0" inputs
    {
        if(input[t] == '0' || input[t] == '1' || input[t] == '.')
        {
            if(input[t] == '.')
            {
                if(flag != 1)
                {
                    flag = 1;
                    t++;
                    continue;
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("\nIncorrect input\n");
                    return 0;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                t++;
                continue;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            printf("\nIncorrect input\n");
            return 0;
        }
    }

    double output = blembo(input);
    printf("%lf\n", output);
    return 0;
}

double blembo (const char *blem)
{
    double x=0, one = 1.0;
    char *p , *fp;
    p = strchr(blem, '.');
    if(p)
    {
        fp = p;
        while(*++fp)
        {
            one = one / 2.0;
            if(*fp == '1')
            {
                x = x + one;
            }
        }
    }
        else
        {
            p = strchr(blem, '\0');
        }

    one = 1.0;
    do
    {
        if(*--p == '1')
        {
            x = x + one;
        }

        one = one * 2.0;
    }
    while(p!=blem);

    return x;
}
```